# How to highlight referenced cells in Excel?

Tags: excel

I want to highlight cells that are referenced somewhere else.

`A1` = 1

`B1` = 1

`C1` = `=SUMM(A1+B1)`

`A1` and `B1` are now referenced in cell `C1`, therefore `A1` and `B1` should turn yellow or red somehow.
How do I do that? With somekind of conditional formatting?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/display-the-relationships-between-formulas-and-cells-a59bef2b-3701-46bf-8ff1-d3518771d507

Comment: @GSerg well I guess that works too. Seems like I didn't know the termology and searched wrong. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that formula inside the rule can help:

> `=SEARCH("**Colored Cell Address**",FORMULATEXT(**Formula Cell Address**))>0`

Comment: Which will find `A1` in `"AREA123"`.

Comment: unfortunately the formular always changes. Sometimes it's "C1 =SUMM(A1+B2)", tomorrow "C3=SUMM(A1:A5)". The formular is always SUMM(something), but what is inside changes daily. The cells should get colored only when they become "Precedent cells".